# How to wait for a function finish in an infinite loop?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a function that must finish its job to restart again, and that for infinite time in nodejs.

So I just want to create an infinite loop, synchronous, that only execute on function.

I tried a lot of things, but all I tested didn't worked.

In other synchronous languages, this function will looks like :

```
while(42) {
myfunc();
}
```

And this function returns a promise.

Can you help me please ?

Comment: `var func = x=>{console.log(x); return new Promise(r=>setTimeout(_=>r(x), 1000))}, loop = x => func(x).then(loop); loop(41).then(console.log)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"And this function returns a promise."

```
myfunc().then(myfunc)
```

UPD. [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/0t813y3c/).

```
function run() {
    myfunc().then(run)
}

run()
```

Comment: this is not working, it does the function one time, then, It stops

Comment: I've updated the answer. You actually need one more function to run the loop.